# How to take benefit of ContextWrapper class for moving functionality from activity to helper class?

Tags: java, android, android-context, applicationcontext

In Android app, I have been making different classes for keeping core code different from activity, but biggest hurdle I found was passing context to each function of core code so that it can do its task as most of the functions need context for processing. I even tried to make generic function but each activity needs to send its context for doing that particular task.

I have few questions:

1. Should I pass generic application context, so that I keep that instance with a base helper class on app start and use same context everywhere in application. This way all functions become independent of activity context? What are the main things I need to take care in this case?
2. I read at one place that I can make helper class an instance of ContextWrapper and I don't need to pass any context for that activity. I tried looking for use of ContextWrapper, but not able to find which I can easily understand. Can someone please help understand this by giving a starting level developer example? I assume this is associated with activity, not for whole application.